# Fake sheet effect

Tags: diagrams

How can recreate this effect in LaTeX?

[image]

Comment: `\includegraphics{thiseffect}` ... What have you tried, how and for what do you want to use it, where are the difficulties?

Comment: @doncherry I would to know if there is a package that provide the creation of similar effects without importing this picture but making a fake shady sheet on the sheet

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's a very basic approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\shade[left color=gray!50,right color=gray!50,middle color=black!55,rounded corners] 
  (-3.4,-5.25) .. controls (0,-5.13) .. (3.4,-5.25) -- (3.4,-4.98) .. controls (0,-4.98) .. (-3.4,-4.98)-- cycle;
\fill[gray!60,rounded corners] 
  (3.6,3.3) .. controls (3.74,4.8) .. (3.76,4.9) --  (3.4,4.95) -- cycle;
\node[fill=gray!15,rectangle,rounded corners,text width=7cm,text height=10cm] 
  at (0,0) (sh) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! :O is possible make the shading effect nuanced from the darkest gray to the lightest outwards until it becomes white? so the border between the shady effect and the white background become nuanced, or better, the passage between the shady effect of the sheet and the white background become nuanced instead of the net passage that be now?

Comment: @FormlessCloud sure; play with the colors used for `left color=`, `right color=`, `middle color=` in the `\shade` options.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina could this be written as a `\renewcommand` for `\includegraphics` to automatically give all images this frame? This could be very attractive for `latex-beamer` presentations.