# How this shading effect would be applied to an mdframed environment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, mdframed

I'd like to apply the following shading effect

[image]

proposed in  " [Fake sheet effect](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70331/fake-sheet-effect) " as a background for a mdframed environment. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Is the gray filled rectangle the text area or where should be the text?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a suggestion whereby I only modified the first frame:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\mdfdefinestyle{fakesheet}{%
backgroundcolor=gray!15,
middlelinecolor=gray!15,
roundcorner=15pt,
 singleextra={%
  \fill[gray!60,rounded corners,] 
  ($(P)+(0,-2.05)$) .. controls  ($(P)+(0.14,-0.55)$) ..  ($(P)+(0.16,-0.45)$) --  ($(P)+(-0.2,-0.4)$) -- cycle;
   \draw[gray!15,line width=0.20cm]  ($(P)+(-.1,-2.15)$)  --  ($(P)+(-.1,-.4)$) ;
\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in ({(\x1-\x2)/2},\y2) coordinate (M);
\shade[left color=gray!50,right color=gray!50,middle color=black!55,rounded corners] 
  ($(M)+(-5.4,-0.135)$) .. controls ($(M)+(0,-0.015)$) .. ($(M)+(5.4,-0.135)$) -- ($(M)+(5.4,0.135)$) .. controls ($(M)+(0,0.135)$) .. ($(M)+(-5.4,0.135)$)-- cycle;
   \draw[gray!15,line width=0.20cm]  ($(M)+(-5.4,0.10)$)  --  ($(M)+(5.4,0.1)$) ;
  }
}


\newmdenv[style=fakesheet]{shadeenv}

\begin{document}
\kant[1]

\begin{shadeenv}
\kant[2]
\end{shadeenv}

\end{document}
```

Extra material can be added by the options `singleextra` `firstextra` etc. See forexample here:

[mdframed-Put something on the start of one vertical left rule](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52023/mdframed-put-something-on-the-start-of-one-vertical-left-rule)